# I want to display div tags according to the type of Props value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to display selected when the type of values is { query: string; isSelect: boolean } and isSelect is true.

> error The property 'isSelect' does not exist for the type '{ query:
> string; isSelect: boolean; } | { query: string; }'.   Property
> 'isSelect' does not exist for type '{ query: string; }'.

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  values: { query: string; isSelect: boolean } | { query: string };
}

export const Category: React.VoidFunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <button onClick={onClick}></button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {values.query}
      </div>
      {values.isSelect &&
      <div>
        selected
     </div>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you need remove this code ` | { query: string };`

Comment: The type of value of props must be { query: string; isSelect: boolean } | { query: string };.

Comment: { query: string };. Is the only way to remove the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the type of values as:

```
{ query: string; isSelect: boolean } | { query: string };
```

Which means that maybe that property exists, and maybe it doesn't. And Typescript will only let you access properties that have been declared somehow.

And since `isSelect` does not exist on `{ query: string }` then you can't access that property.

However, if you declare the property as optional, then you are saying it can be omitted, but you are still allowed to access it:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  onClick: () => void;
  values: { query: string; isSelect?: boolean };
  //                               ^ this here makes the property optional
}
```

Then it works as you expect.

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOABRzAGc4BvUuOSlEEgBccNjChUA5gG4ecCJQDCAG2BoA1iIAUASjgBeAHxwAbhGAATWbxMplAVyRsRnOAEdHUAJ4ixEyjJwwGwAykjKSBgA-CIARhAQESiUcAC+sqnkSAAekLBwaApicIooNJLQPojEMAB0AGrmFgBi9pQYwAqKuJCUSNQAPCwQ7Mb6cFqu-IIANPJKqhpztg5OqXpGXHJEMPZQKVpyvAMWwCaGR7xwJ2cXV-fXYIac00ipAwD0T5f3A7H2MBgCnmKjU6n0nC6i3UqUMn3+gIUdwen1O5x+1zRyIeXBWjjYtQ8tC8mRxqNuGM4eKctWCYQiGDgADImRjjli2Q82OFIjQLJzyeicaSroLkToMtIgA) with no type errors.

---

Alternatively, if you did not want to change the type, you can check for the presence of the property with the `in` operator.

```
{'isSelect' in values && values.isSelect &&
  <div>
    selected
  </div>
}
```

This tells typescript that you tested at runtime which branch of the union type this value is, and then lets you access that property once you've proven it exists. This is called [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=19&ssc=7&pln=23&pc=8#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOABRzAGc4BvUuOSlEEgBccNjChUA5gG4ecCJQDCAG2BoA1iIAUASjgBeAHxwAbhGAATWbxMplAVyRsRnOAEdHUAJ4ixEyjJwwGwAykjKSBgiAEYQEBEolHAAvnAAPlzunj6i4lIpssnkSAAekLBwaApicIooNJLQOcjoMAB0AGrmFgBi9pQYwAqKuJCUSNQAPCwQ7Mb6cFqu-IIANPJKqhrrtg5OyXpGXHJEMPZQSVpyvJMWwCaG17xwt-ePzx8vYIacK0jJkwA9N8nh9JtF7DAYAoNio1Op9Jxhlt1MlDECIVCFO9PkC7g9QS98TjPlxdo42G0PLQvEVSXi3oTOPhgmEIiQgklyU44AAyXmmOwUtqs8KReD8wk3YlSz5sMUYJAWWUMgmkunPVU4nSFaRAA)